# Guardar arreglo multidimensional en localStorage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json, script

quiero guardar varios formularios en localStorage, lo que hago es tomo el nombre del formulario + un id para que tome el formulario correcto, al guardarlos los guardo de una forma muy similar, creando una variable + un id pero para traerlos no sé como puedo hacer para que me traiga el formulario que estoy pidiendo, por ejemplo para guardar traigo 'valor' que es igual a 1 entonces mi variable = form1, y lo guardo como localStorage.setItem('probando'+valor,variable), entonces quedaria guardado en localStorage.probando1, pero al cargar si pongo un console.log(localstorage.provando+valor) me aparece indefinido, espero me hayan podido entender, de igual manera les dejo el código.

```js
function prueba(valor) {
    // localStorage.clear();

    let variablep = $("#form" + valor).serialize();
    localStorage.setItem('probando'+valor,JSON.stringify(variablep));
}

function cargarprueba(valor) {
    console.log(localStorage.probando[valor]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto

```
localStorage.probando[valor]
//si valor="ALGO", lo de arriba es lo mismo que localStorage.probando.ALGO, es decir
//estas buscando la propiedad que esta dentro de la propiedad "probando"
```

Debes cambiarlo por:

```
localStorage["probando" + valor]
//ejemplo localStorage["probando1"]
```

Lo cual si bien puede funcionar no es la forma [documentada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para obtener un valor del `localStorage`. El cual se obtiene utilizando la función `getItem(valor)`

```
localStorage.getItem("probando" + valor)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso solucionó mi problema